# Change *Completions* list to sort vertically?

Tags: completion

When you trigger minibuffer completion for a partial command/filename/etc., the *Completions* buffer lists possible completions aligned vertically (in columns) but *sorted* horizontally.

```
../                ./                   ajax-proj/         algorithms/
angular-phone/     angular/             annex/             archives/
blog-ideas/        clojure-koans/       ctags58/           diff-tryout/
encodings/         filters/             game-table/        git-grounds/
hartl/             invoice_angel/       jQuery-basics/     java/
making/            ng-fundamentals/     node-meetup/       pickaxe/
```

I find this much more difficult to scan than if they were sorted vertically, like Bash does.

```
../                annex/               encodings/         jQuery-basics/
./                 archives/            filters/           java/
ajax-proj/         blog-ideas/          game-table/        making/
algorithms/        clojure-koans/       git-grounds/       ng-fundamentals/
angular-phone/     ctags58/             hartl/             node-meetup/
angular/           diff-tryout/         invoice_angel/     pickaxe/
```

Is there a setting that controls this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is the variable `completions-format` (since Emacs 23.2). Just set it to `'vertical`.

Comment: Holy cow! Despite Emacs' wealth of configurability, I keep running into really annoying aspects that don't have an easy solution. Happy to hear this is not one of them. `completions-format` is *exactly* what I was looking for, and setting it to `'vertical` did the trick. Thank you!

Comment: Yes, I know the feeling … To be honest, I didn't know about this one myself. Ironically, I found out about it by browsing the documentation for icicles, pointed to by @Drew's answer.

Comment: Hah, that really *is* ironic :)

Comment: i am used to the [tag:unix] `ls` command which sorts vertically by default; also this customizable variable is not in the existing `completion` group but in the minibuffer customization group (residing in [minibuffer.el](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/emacs.git/tree/lisp/minibuffer.el#n1523)) acessible by `customize-group minibuffer`

Answer (score 1):

You can easily do this if you use [Icicles](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Icicles) - see [Vertical Layout](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Icicles_-_Completions_Display#VerticalLayout).

You can make this the default behavior by customizing option [**`icicle-completions-format`**](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Icicles_-_Customization_and_General_Tips#icicle-completions-format) to have the value `vertical`.

And you can toggle between horizontal and vertical layout anytime during completion, using **`C-M-^`**.

This affects *all* minibuffer completion, whether by `completing-read` or `read-file-name` (or anything else that uses these).